# Checking for IE7/IE6 in jQuery

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-6, detection

I have a function where it needs to make allowances for the fact IE6/IE7 does not have the same support as other browsers, as follows:

```
if ($.browser.msie && $.browser.version.substr(0,1)<8) {
  $('table tr:nth-child(2n+1)').addClass('alternativeRow');
}
```

This has always worked fine, until I've just installed IE8 and I get a Javascript error message saying:

> '$.browser' is null or not an object

I appreciate $.browser may not be the best way of checking these things anyway, so I was wondering if there was a way around it?

Thanks

(edit) to add a little context, I am simply trying to add a 'zebra' esque table layout since we deal with lots of data and it can be hard to analyse if each row looks the same

Comment: That sounds like jQuery didn't load properly or was used before loading. In my experience, it works in IE8 the same way.

Comment: Looks like jQuery hasn't loaded correctly. Try loading it off Google's CDN: http://code.google.com/apis/libraries/devguide.html#jquery and try again

Comment: `$.browser` works for me in IE6, IE7, IE8 and IE9

Comment: Damn! You guys were right, it was a conflict with something I was using called 'Slimbox' - will fix now :) THANK YOU!

Answer (score 1):

Quit Browser Sniffing and start feature sniffing.

[http://modernizr.com/](http://www.modernizr.com/)

Comment: Looks a good solution, thanks! I need a fix for now but will definitely look into implementing this asap

Answer (score 1):

.browser was deprecated in jQuery 1.3. The recommended solution is to use [.support](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.support/)